# Autoscroll is not working on dynamic form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, scrollbar

I have a form with a button on it that will dynamically create a new form. I add all the labels, textboxes and buttons on the fly based on a text file. I thought I would be able to use the "**frmDynamic.AutoScroll = True**" command to add scroll bars if there are too many controls on the form but it is not working.
Here is the related settings to the form

```
 frmDynamic = New Form()
            frmDynamic.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0F, 13.0F)
            frmDynamic.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
            frmDynamic.Name = "frmDynamicMerchantApplication"

            'dimension is irrelevant at the moment
            frmDynamic.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(10, 10)
            'the parent will be the current form
            'frm.MdiParent = this;

            frmDynamic.ControlBox = True
            frmDynamic.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable
            ' This needs to be GrowOnly for the auto scroll to work. - otherwise you have to add scrollbars manually along with the handlers and so forth.
            frmDynamic.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly

            ' Add auto scroll since the form could grow out of range when adding multiple references and owners
            frmDynamic.AutoScroll = True
```

In addition I attempted to set the "**pad.AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 0)**" property also but nothing seems to work - I get no scroll bar.

As a final test I have set the AutoScroll property to true on the main form and it works fine when the form is sized smaller than the objects positions. As a final test I added another button on the main form with the following code to create a form with autoscroll set to true and it works fine.

```
 ' Create a new form.
        Dim form2 As New Form()
        ' Create a button to add to the new form.
        Dim button1 As New Button()
        ' Set text for the button.
        button1.Text = "Scrolled Button"
        ' Set the size of the button.
        button1.Size = New Size(100, 30)
        ' Set the location of the button to be outside the form's client area.
        button1.Location = New Point(form2.Size.Width + 200, form2.Size.Height + 200)

        ' Add the button control to the new form.
        form2.Controls.Add(button1)
        ' Set the AutoScroll property to true to provide scrollbars.
        form2.AutoScroll = True

        ' Display the new form as a dialog box.
        form2.ShowDialog()
```

Is there any form settings that could be stopping this functionality?

Here is the entire form creation code:

```
 ' Creating dynamic form and dynamic objects in it.
        If Not IsNothing(colMerchApplicationFromWebService) Then
            ' vertical position of current object we are working with on the form
            Dim intVertPos As Integer = 35

            'variables to hold dimensions for objects on the form. Used in calculations for creating objects and their placement
            Dim intMaxWidthLabel As Integer = 0
            Dim intMaxWidthText As Integer = 0
            Dim iFrmMaxHeight As Integer = 0
            Dim intWidthTextBox As Integer = 0
            Dim intGapHeight As Integer = 0
            Dim measureString As String = ""
            Dim stringFont As Font = Nothing
            Dim stringSize As SizeF
            Dim iTabIndex As Integer = 0
            Dim iNewLineCount As Integer = 0
            Dim iNewColumnPosition As Integer = 0

            ' Font settings
            Dim sFont As String = "Arial"
            Dim sSizeFont As String = "10"
            Dim sTextSize As String = "15"
            Dim pictureBox1 As New PictureBox

            ' use an invisible picture box that will help to graphically
            ' measure strings according their font and font size
            Dim myGraphics As Graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics()

            ' Calculate the height gap that has to be generated for this calculation, we have to follow the principles listed:
            '   The gap should be determined only by the height of the tallest object on window: the textBox.
            '   Simulate the drawing of a dummy textBox, that will never be shown, and retrieve its height for spacing purposes.
            Dim dummyTextBox As New TextBox()
            dummyTextBox.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(sFont, Single.Parse(sSizeFont), System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CByte(0))
            Dim intHeight As Integer = Integer.Parse(sSizeFont) + Integer.Parse(sSizeFont) / 2
            dummyTextBox.Name = "TextBoxDummy"
            intGapHeight = dummyTextBox.Height

            'close the dynamic form if existing already
            If frmDynamic IsNot Nothing Then
                frmDynamic.Close()
            End If

            ' Now create a new fresh one
            frmDynamic = New Form()
            frmDynamic.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0F, 13.0F)
            frmDynamic.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
            frmDynamic.Name = "frmDynamicMerchantApplication"

            'dimension is irrelevant at the moment
            frmDynamic.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(10, 10)
            'the parent will be the current form
            'frm.MdiParent = this;

            frmDynamic.ControlBox = True
            frmDynamic.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable
            ' This needs to be GrowOnly for the auto scroll to work. - otherwise you have to add scrollbars manually along with the handlers and so forth.
            frmDynamic.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly

            ' Add auto scroll since the form could grow out of range when adding multiple references and owners
            frmDynamic.AutoScroll = True
            frmDynamic.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray

            'for each parameter returned add a data entry control to the form
            For Each itemMerchantAppField As TestApp.parameter In colMerchApplicationFromWebService
                ' if we run into a collection it is used for detailed information. We store the collections in the collections dictionary so we can write values and pass them around as needed
                If itemMerchantAppField.ParameterType = "System.Collections" Then
                    ' Create a form level variable to hold the collection
                    dicCollections.Add(itemMerchantAppField.ParameterName, itemMerchantAppField.SubCollection)
                End If

                ' I assume a max of 35 fields in one column for my form and its size. (The field count is based on what looked right for my monitor not exactly Dynamic but its only a test form) 
                If iNewLineCount > 35 Then
                    ' Reset vertical position and counter
                    iNewLineCount = 0
                    iNewColumnPosition = iNewColumnPosition + (intMaxWidthLabel + intMaxWidthText + 20)
                    If intVertPos > iFrmMaxHeight Then
                        iFrmMaxHeight = intVertPos
                    End If
                    intVertPos = 35
                End If

                ' Kick the counter
                iNewLineCount = iNewLineCount + 1

                'add a label object
                Dim aLabel As New Label()
                aLabel.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(sFont, Single.Parse(sSizeFont), System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CByte(0))
                'back color is for testing purposes, to see if the control fits correctly
                aLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue
                aLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(iNewColumnPosition, intVertPos)

                ' Set up string.
                measureString = itemMerchantAppField.ParameterName
                stringFont = New Font(sFont, Single.Parse(sSizeFont))
                ' Measure string.
                stringSize = New SizeF()
                stringSize = myGraphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont)
                Dim intWidthLabel As Integer = 10 + Integer.Parse(stringSize.Width.ToString("####0"))
                'store the biggest width, so that the textboxes can be vertically aligned
                If intWidthLabel > intMaxWidthLabel Then
                    intMaxWidthLabel = intWidthLabel
                End If
                aLabel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(intWidthLabel, intGapHeight)
                aLabel.Name = "lbl" & itemMerchantAppField.ParameterName
                aLabel.Text = itemMerchantAppField.ParameterName

                frmDynamic.SuspendLayout()
                aLabel.SuspendLayout()
                frmDynamic.Controls.Add(aLabel)

                ' Size of textBox padding with "W" the largest char in ascii representation.
                ' Basically we are setting the textbox widths based on the lengths of the field name plus 15 w's
                ' We should be setting this based on the allowed field length as w's up to the max amount we allow(here is it coded to be 30)
                ' this section needs to be corrected
                Dim chrPadding As Char = "W"c
                If Integer.Parse(sTextSize) > 30 Then
                    measureString = measureString.PadRight(30, chrPadding)
                Else
                    measureString = measureString.PadRight(Integer.Parse(sTextSize), chrPadding)
                End If
                stringFont = New Font(sFont, Single.Parse(sSizeFont))
                ' Measure string.
                stringSize = New SizeF()
                stringSize = myGraphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont)
                intWidthTextBox = Integer.Parse(stringSize.Width.ToString("####0"))

                ''For Each item As wsMerchantApp.parameter In itemMerchantAppField 
                ' Add a text box object
                Dim aTextBox As New TextBox()
                aTextBox.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(sFont, Single.Parse(sSizeFont), System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CByte(0))
                aTextBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
                aTextBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(iNewColumnPosition + 5 + intMaxWidthLabel, intVertPos)
                aTextBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(intWidthTextBox + 10, intGapHeight)

                ' Add a double click handler for each text box - I use this for getting additional information on the field in focus
                AddHandler aTextBox.DoubleClick, AddressOf TextBoxShowDesc

                'store the biggest width, so that the textboxes can be vertically aligned
                If intWidthTextBox > intMaxWidthText Then
                    intMaxWidthText = intWidthTextBox
                End If

                ' giving a name to all your objects will be the only way to retrieve them and use them in code. I use the names from
                ' the parameter class so it is easier to work with
                aTextBox.Name = itemMerchantAppField.ParameterName
                'giving the maximum size in characters for the textbox.
                aTextBox.MaxLength = Integer.Parse(itemMerchantAppField.ParameterLength)
                ' Create a useful tooltip
                ToolTip1.SetToolTip(aTextBox, itemMerchantAppField.ParameterDesc & IIf(itemMerchantAppField.ParameterRequired, " This field is required.", " This field is not required."))

                'tab have to be ordered so we can navigate the form with ease
                aTextBox.TabIndex = iTabIndex
                ' Now kick the counter
                iTabIndex += 1

                'Vertical position is to be manage according the 
                'tallest object in the form, in this case the textbox it self
                intVertPos += intGapHeight

                'adding the textbox to the form
                frmDynamic.SuspendLayout()
                aTextBox.SuspendLayout()
                frmDynamic.Controls.Add(aTextBox)
            Next

            'put an action button to the right
            Dim btnFill As Button = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
            btnFill.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(iNewColumnPosition + (intMaxWidthLabel + intMaxWidthText), 0) 'intMaxWidthLabel + intWidthTextBox + 20, 0)
            btnFill.Name = "btnFill"
            btnFill.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
            btnFill.TabIndex = iTabIndex
            btnFill.Text = "&Fill"

            'put another action button to the under the first
            Dim btnSendApp As Button = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
            btnSendApp.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(iNewColumnPosition + (intMaxWidthLabel + intMaxWidthText), 0 + intGapHeight) 'intMaxWidthLabel + intWidthTextBox + 20, 0)
            btnSendApp.Name = "btnSubmit"
            btnSendApp.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
            btnSendApp.TabIndex = iTabIndex
            btnSendApp.Text = "&Submit"

            'define a click_event on the buttons - now we can handle the click event code in the parent form.
            AddHandler btnFill.Click, AddressOf btnFillClick
            AddHandler btnSendApp.Click, AddressOf btnSendAppClick

            ' Add the buttons
            frmDynamic.Controls.Add(btnFill)
            frmDynamic.Controls.Add(btnSendApp)

            ' Grow the form if needed to fir objects
            frmDynamic.Width = iNewColumnPosition + (intMaxWidthLabel + intMaxWidthText + 95) 'intMaxWidthLabel + intMaxWidthText + 95
            frmDynamic.Height = iFrmMaxHeight + 35 'intVertPos + 35
            If frmDynamic.Height > Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height OrElse frmDynamic.Width > Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width Then
                ' If the form is too big we should warn the user. 
                MessageBox.Show("Beware! The size of the window is bigger than your actual definitions...", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            End If

            frmDynamic.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("ERROR: Nothing returned from the web service. The form can not be created.")
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick test, I can confirm that your code is fine; most likely, you didn't do the right tests. Below I am adding a couple of bits into your first code to show the point:

```
frmDynamic = New Form()
frmDynamic.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0F, 13.0F)
frmDynamic.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
frmDynamic.Name = "frmDynamicMerchantApplication"

'dimension is irrelevant at the moment
frmDynamic.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 50)
'the parent will be the current form
'frm.MdiParent = this;

frmDynamic.ControlBox = True
frmDynamic.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable
' This needs to be GrowOnly for the auto scroll to work. - otherwise you have to add scrollbars manually along with the handlers and so forth.
frmDynamic.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly

' Add auto scroll since the form could grow out of range when adding multiple references and owners
frmDynamic.AutoScroll = True

Dim testButton As New Button()
frmDynamic.Controls.Add(testButton)
testButton.Top = frmDynamic.Height + 1

frmDynamic.Show()
```

This code shows a poping up form and the corresponding vertical scrollbar (I increased the size because otherwise you cannot even see the scrollbar, but this has no effect at all).

If now you change the location of `testButton` to -1 (or -100), the scrollbar would stop appearing; I guess that this is the responsible for you not seeing the scrollbars: a wrongly-positioned testing object.

-- UPDATE

After looking at your whole code, the problem seems to be in all the `frmDynamic.SuspendLayout()` bits ([information in MSDN about this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)), just delete them. It is a good thing knowing what does each bit of your code exactly. Also, when you have a problem which you cannot understand and a proper-working code (the one in this answer), no matter how simple it is; a good proceeding is starting to include bits from the faulty code in the working one, step by step, until finding where the problem is.

Comment: Below the code I posted where I am setting the form attributes is code that is inserting about 150 text boxes and labels as well as a few buttons that I did not bother posting being that there is a lot of code.

Comment: @DanRowe you can test my code (30 seconds of your time) and will see that it works fine. Clearly the location of all these objects is not "outside the frame of the form". Post the whole code (or a link) and I can take a quick look at it.

Comment: Interesting that adding the resume layout command did not work until I moved the suspend call to before the for loop.

Comment: @DanRowe This is just somehow unexpected. Bear in mind that GUI elements (or properties affecting GUI elements) and loops are not good friends: if possible is better having any GUI-related element outside a loop. On the other hand, I don't see the exact point of using SuspendLayout in this code but well... at least, now you know how it works.